# Possible jQuery bug parsing HTML

Tags: jquery

I just discovered this issue, and I wanted to run it by everyone here to make sure I wasn't missing obvious something before I reported it.

Here is what's causing me a problem:

```
html = '<html><body><div id="test">This is just a test</div></body></html>';
alert( $(html).find('#test').html() );
```

The alert window shows `null` instead of the text inside `#test`. **HOWEVER**, if I simply wrap `<div id="test">` in another `div` element, it works properly and returns the expected, "This is just a test".

This code works:

```
html = '<html><body><div><div id="test">This is just a test</div></div></body></html>';
alert( $(html).find('#test').html() );
```

Can someone explain to me why this would be happening? Why would the second example work but the first one not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you debug what `$(html)` does, you will notice it only creates the DOM tree for the “usefull” contents, here the `div#test` block (it strips the html and body containers).
Thing is, `find()` looks for children of the element you're calling it from. As the root element of $(html) is already your `div#test` element, you will not be able to search for itself using `find`.

This also explains why wrapping a “container” element makes your code work.

**EDIT**
A simple workaround would be, as the OP said, to warp the html into a container such as a div:

```
var content = $('<div/>').append(html);
content.find('#test'); // returns the right div
```

Comment: +1 of course, however this will also work using the first HTML: `alert($(html).find('#test').andSelf().html());` :)

Comment: Upon further inspection, this does not work. Try your same alert but instead of passing `#test`, pass `#wrongid`. You'll see it still (incorrectly) alerts the html from `#test`.

Comment: Indeed, this code doest not do what I was expecting. My explanation remains right but your workaround is imho the simplest working trick. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: Yes, I would not have come up with my solution without your and Effata's answers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the jQuery parser strips away everything but the body. If you do a console.log you get these results:

```
html = '<html><body><div id="test">This is just a test</div></body></html>';
console.log( $(html) );
= [<div id=​"test">​This is just a test​</div>​]
```

Which means you run find on the #test div itself, hence you won't get a result.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Effata and @Zopieux for helping me figure this out. @Effata, unfortunately your trick doesn't seem to work. If you pass it an incorrect selector (such as `#wrongid`), it still seems to return the contents of `#test`.

Here is the solution I found that seems to work for all situations. Basically all I'm doing is wrapping the HTML in a `<div>` before executing the `.find()` method.

```
html = '<html><body><div id="test">This is just a test</div></body></html>';
alert( $("<div />").append(html).find("#test").html() );
```